# Restrict Post back for input button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="return fnClearFields();" />


function fnClearFields() {

   var datePickerStart = $find("<%= radDatePicker_StartDate.ClientID %>");
   datePickerStart.clear();

   var maskedtxtboxStart = $find("<%= radMaskedtxt_StartDate.ClientID %>");
   maskedtxtboxStart.set_value("");                

   return false;
}
```

Comment: You need explain more about your problem. You just send a part of code, it's not cleat.

Comment: You might be getting a javascript error and "return false;" statement is not being executed. Use F12 to check for Jscript errors.